# Student's t alpha change

Tags: r

I need to run several one sample t-tests. Is there a way of changing the alpha level for this test? or, is it necessary to do some kind of correction for a one sample t test? (like a bonferroni correction for a paired t test) ?
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to apply the `t.test` to one data with different alphas, or to different sample dataset and each time with different alphas?

Comment: I have different data sets, and just need to specify one alpha value

Comment: One alpha value? so why you stated in your question "way of changing the alpha level"?. That does not sound like a unique alpha, anyway try to be more clear next time. anyway  There are several ways to to that but without a piece of your data it is hard, just guessing. You can combine your datasets in a list and then `lapply(data, t.test)` or combine each data like a column of a data frame and then `sapply(data, t.test)`

Answer (score 2):

The `t.test` function returns a p-value

```
t.test(rnorm(10))$p.value
```

You can set the cut-off. The function does have an argument `conf.level` for the confidence interval.

To correct for multiple comparisons, see `p.adjust`.

```
p_values = c(0.1, 0.01, 0.05)
p.adjust(p_values, method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.30 0.03 0.15
```

Comment: In comments OP says that the alpha level is one, furthermore he/she says that it has to apply the t.test to several data. I do not understand how your answer can be of any help.

Comment: In the question, the OP wants to run several t-tests and correct for multiple comparisons (I tried to answer that question). Regarding the comment, after doing the multiple comparison correction using `p.adjust`, we can then specify one "alpha" value at the correct significance level.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of the `t.test` you may have noticed that the output is independent of alpha. The test gives you information you would need to make decisions but the decision criteria are not in it. For that reason it's difficult for people to help you because your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the `t.test` R command. I do caution against adjusting the p-values post-hoc using `p.adjust`. This is especially problematic because many adjustments are actually varying alpha (but, as you indicate Bonferroni uses a single one). It is much more honest reporting to report your modified alpha value which, for Bonferroni, is just `0.05 /` number of tests.