# Is it possible to change Type I error threshold using t.test() function?

Tags: r

I am asked to compute a test statistic using the `t.test()` function, but I need to reduce the type I error. My prof showed us how to change a confidence level for this function, but not the acceptable type I error for null hypothesis testing. The goal is for the argument to automatically compute a p-value based on a .01 error rate rather than the normal .05.

The r code below involves a data set that I have downloaded.

```
t.test(mid$log_radius_area, mu=8.456)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141294/students-t-alpha-change

Comment: p-values are used in the Fisherian version of statistical testing. Confidence levels are used in the Neyman-Pearson version of statistical testing, where one sets a level and then accepts or rejects. The current mode of teaching statistics usually communicates a mish-mash of those two incompatible frameworks, leaving students  often confused.

Answer (score 0):

*I feel like I've answered this somewhere, but can't seem to find it on SO or CrossValidated.*

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141294/students-t-alpha-change), the answer is that `t.test()` doesn't specify *any* threshold for rejecting/failing to reject the null hypothesis; it reports a p-value, and you get to decide whether to reject or not. (The `conf.level` argument is for adjusting which *confidence interval* the output reports.)

From `?t.test`:

```
t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  1:10 and c(7:20)
t = -5.4349, df = 21.982, p-value = 1.855e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.052802  -4.947198
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      5.5      13.5
```

Here the p-value is reported as 1.855e-05, so the null hypothesis would be rejected for any (**pre-specified**) alpha level >1.855e-05. Note that the output doesn't say anywhere "the null hypothesis is rejected at alpha=0.05" or anything like that.  You *could* write your own function to do that, using the `$p.value` element that is saved as part of the test results:

```
report_test <- function(tt, alpha=0.05) {
    cat("the null hypothesis is ")
    if (tt$p.value > alpha) {
       cat("**NOT** ")
    }
    cat("rejected at alpha=",alpha,"\n")
}
tt <- t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))
report_test(tt)
## the null hypothesis is rejected at alpha= 0.05
```

Most R package/function writers don't bother to do this, because they figure that it should be simple enough for users to do for themselves.

Comment: You know, you're totally right. I just goofed. I'm not sure why I was thinking that a changed threshold would change the computed p-value. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: if this answered your question, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it. (If you decide that your question is not actually meaningful and is unlikely to help others in the future [although we have seen questions like this before!], you can delete it.)